# Видео с Yotube - проблема

Tags: html5

И так у нас есть видео с ютуба(любое) !
Пример:

```html
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ВАШЕВИДЕО?autoplay=1&controls=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Нужно убрать надпись ютуб , в документации пишет чтоб использовать modestbranding=1 , но оно не работает!
Возможно есть другой сервис для загрузки видео на сайт , но чтоб все выглядело  как трансляция , то есть без логотипов , панели управления и тд.!
Вставка видео через  не подходит!

Comment: http://vimeo.com/

Comment: https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=2425&rub=37

Comment: Надпись есть также!